# Observer pattern + Visitor pattern for message system

Tags: c++, c++11, observer-pattern, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

Recently I got into implementing a message dispatching system that uses the "Observer pattern": nothing special here. As I developed it I thought it would be nice to send "Message" objects from the "subject" that could be fundamentally different from each other and could be read from the many "observers".

These different messages took the form of different message classes (for example, think about the "User Logout message", "Screen mode toogle" and "Volume level changed", all of these need different information) and soon I found that the "observers" needed not to know about every different message I would want to create (that would be... unsustainable, to say the least). Instead, I would like each observer to be able to react to specific kinds of messages.

So in order to make something I thought that double dispatching could be my option here. After a litte I got this piece (c++11 only because of the for loop):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

/**
* A few forward declarations.
*/

class Message_base;
class Message_type_a;
class Message_type_b;

/**
* Base observer...
*/

class Observer_base
{
    public:

    /**
    * All these implementations are empty so we don't have to specify them
    * in every single derived class.
    */

    virtual void        get_message(const Message_base&) {}
    virtual void        get_message(const Message_type_a&) {}
    virtual void        get_message(const Message_type_b&) {}
};

/**
* Specification of all message types.
*/

class Message_base
{
    public:

    /**
    * This is the method that will implement the double dispatching in all
    * derived classes.
    */

    virtual void        be_recieved(Observer_base &r) const=0;  //Now that's a nasty method name.
};

class Message_type_a:public Message_base
{
    private:
    int integer_value;

    public:
                Message_type_a(int v):integer_value(v) {}
    int             get_integer_value() const {return integer_value;}
    void            be_recieved(Observer_base &r) const {r.get_message(*this);}

};

class Message_type_b:public Message_base
{
    private:
    std::string string_value;

    public:
                Message_type_b(const std::string v):string_value(v) {}
    std::string         get_string_value() const {return string_value;}
    void            be_recieved(Observer_base &r) const {r.get_message(*this);}
};

/**
* This is the base clase for the Subject... Notice that there are no virtual
* methods so we could as well instantiate this class instead of derive it.
*/

class Subject_base
{
    private:

    std::vector<Observer_base *>    observers;

    public:

    void            emit_message(const Message_base& m) {for(auto o : observers) m.be_recieved(*o);}    //Again, nasty to read since it's... backwards.
    void            register_observer(Observer_base * o) {observers.push_back(o);} 
};

/**
* Now we will create a subject class for the sake of it. We could just call the
* public "emit_message" from main passing Message objects.
*/

class Subject_derived:public Subject_base
{
    public:

    void            emit_message_a(int v) {emit_message(Message_type_a(v));}
    void            emit_message_b(const std::string v) {emit_message(Message_type_b(v));}
};

/**
* This gets fun... We make two observers. One will only get type_a messages
* and the other will get type_b.
*/

class Observer_type_a:public Observer_base
{
    private:

    int             index;  //We will use it to identify the observer.

    public:

                Observer_type_a(int i):index(i) {}
    void            get_message(const Message_type_a& m) {std::cout<<"Observer_type_a ["<<index<<"] : got type_a message : "<<m.get_integer_value()<<std::endl;}
};

class Observer_type_b:public Observer_base
{
    private:

    std::string         name; //Merely to identify the observer.

    public:

                Observer_type_b(const std::string& n):name(n) {}
    void            get_message(const Message_type_b& m) {std::cout<<"Observer_type_b ["<<name<<"] : got type_b message : "<<m.get_string_value()<<std::endl;}
};

/**
* Stitch all pieces together.
*/

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Observer_type_a o_a1(1);
    Observer_type_a o_a2(2);
    Observer_type_b o_b1("Sauron");
    Observer_type_b o_b2("Roverandom");

    Subject_derived s_a;

    s_a.register_observer(&o_a1);
    s_a.register_observer(&o_b1);

    s_a.emit_message_a(23);
    s_a.emit_message_b("this is my content");

    s_a.register_observer(&o_a2);
    s_a.register_observer(&o_b2);

    s_a.emit_message_a(99);
    s_a.emit_message_b("this is my second content");

    //gloriously exit.  
    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of clarity I will speak my goals here:

- Be able to send many different messages from the Subject.
- Specialize the observers to they ignore every message not meant for them (it would be even nicer if they weren't sent at all, but I know I can make that registering different groups of observers).
- Avoid RTTI and derived class casting.

Here comes my question: Have I missed a simpler implementation to achieve my goals?.

It is important to mention that the system this will be used on will not have that many observers and maybe less than ten subjects present at the same time.

Comment: It is just an impression I have, but I think C++ people tend to shun over the Gang of Four material. I particularly wouldn't use Observer pattern in a C++ project, but instead would go with something in the line of Boost::Signals2, and use templates do register function objects. My line of thinking is something like: "Heck, with C++11 std::function and lambdas, why would anyone want to use the full blown Observer pattern? That is for Java programmers."

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't really have a formative background on the GOF or anything "software engineering" related so I wouldn't know about that. To be fair it is the first time ever I have used this pattern. Now, double dispatching is something I am familiar with :) (you know, when all you know are hammers everything is a nail). Anyways, any suggestions involving any other methods are welcome. How would that Boost thing go?.

Comment: Why would you want to register an observer for a message it cannot understand?

Comment: Clearly because I don't know any better ;). I wanted a simple to read and understand solution for this particular case. It does not scale and does waste cycles but it's easy to read and understand for beginner-intermediate monkey coders. As evidenced by the answers below, I"ve still a long way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Some metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
// a bundle of types:
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

// a type that does nothing but carry a type around
// without being that type:
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};

// a template that undoes the `tag` operation above:
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

// a shorter way to say `std::integral_constant<size_t, x>`:
template<std::size_t i>struct index:std::integral_constant<std::size_t, i>{};
```

Get the index of a type in a `types<...>`:

```
// this code takes a type T, and a types<...> and returns
// the index of the type in there.
// index_of
namespace details {
  template<class T, class Types>
  struct index_of{};
}
template<class T, class Types>
using index_of_t=type_t<details::index_of<T,Types>>;
namespace details {
  // if the first entry in the list of types is T,
  // our value is 0
  template<class T, class...Ts>struct index_of<T, types<T,Ts...>>:
    tag< index<0> >
  {};
  // otherwise, it is 1 plus our value on the tail of the list:
  template<class T, class T0, class...Ts>
  struct index_of<T, types<T0, Ts...>>:
    tag< index< index_of_t<T,types<Ts...>{}+1 > >
  {};
}
```

Here is a single "channel" broadcaster (it sends one kind of message):

```
// a token is a shared pointer to anything
// below, it tends to be a shared pointer to a std::function
// all we care about is the lifetime, however:
using token = std::shared_ptr<void>;
template<class M>
struct broadcaster {
  // f is the type of something that can eat our message:
  using f = std::function< void(M) >;
  // we keep a vector of weak pointers to people who can eat
  // our message.  This lets them manage lifetime independently:
  std::vector<std::weak_ptr<f>> listeners;

  // reg is register.  You pass in a function to eat the message
  // it returns a token.  So long as the token, or a copy of it,
  // survives, broadcaster will continue to send stuff at the
  // function you pass in:
  token reg( f target ) {
    // if thread safe, (write)lock here
    auto sp = std::make_shared<f>(std::move(target));
    listeners.push_back( sp );
    return sp;
    // unlock here
  }
  // removes dead listeners:
  void trim() {
    // if thread safe, (try write)lock here
    // and/or have trim take a lock as an argument
    listeners.erase(
      std::remove_if( begin(listeners), end(listeners), [](auto&& p){
        return p.expired();
      } ),
      listeners.end()
    );
    // unlock here
  }
  // Sends a message M m to every listener who is not dead:
  void send( M m ) {
    trim(); // remove dead listeners
    // (read) lock here
    auto tmp_copy = listeners; // copy the listeners, just in case
    // unlock here

    for (auto w:tmp_copy) {
      auto p = w.lock();
      if (p) (*p)(m);
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a multi-channel `subject` that can support any number of different message types (determined at compile-time).  If you fail to match a message type, `send` and/or `reg` will fail to compile.  You are responsible for deciding if a message is a `const&` or a value or whatever.  Trying to `reg` an rvalue message won't work.  It is intended that `M` is passed to `reg` and `send` explicitly.

```
// fancy wrapper around a tuple of broadcasters:
template<class...Ts>
struct subject {
  std::tuple<broadcaster<Ts>...> stations;
  // helper function that gets a broadcaster compatible
  // with a message type M:
  template<class M>
  broadcaster<M>& station() {
    return std::get< index_of_t<M, types<Ts...>>{} >( stations );
  }
  // register a message of type M.  You should call with M explicit usually:
  template<class M>
  token reg( std::function<void(M)> listener ) {
    return station<M>().reg(std::move(listener));
  }
  // send a message of type M.  You should explicitly pass M usually:
  template<class M>
  void send( M m ) {
    station<M>().send(std::forward<M>(m));
  }
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b08e88e720cd8bfa).

When you `reg`, it returns a `token`, aka `std::shared_ptr<void>`.  For as long as this token (or a copy) survives, messages will flow.  If it goes away, messages to the reged callback will end.  Typically that means listeners should maintain a `std::vector<token>`, and reg lambdas that use `this` willy-nilly.

In C++14/1z, the above gets a bit nicer (we can do away with `types<...>` and `index_of` for one).

If you add a listener during a broadcast cycle, it will not be sent to.  If you remove a listener during a broadcast cycle, it will not be sent to after the point you removed it.

The thread safe comments are set up for reader/writer locks on broadcaster.

Memory allocated for dead listeners for a given broadcaster is reclaimed when `trim` or `send` is called.  However, the `std::function` will have been destroyed long ago, so only a limited amount of memory is wasted until the next `send`.  I do it then, because we are going to iterate over the list of messages anyhow, might as well clean up any mess first.

This solution has no RTTI or dynamic casting, and messages are only sent to listeners who understand them.

---

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) things gets simpler.  Drop all of the metaprogramming boilerplate, remove `subject` (keep `broadcaster`) and just do this to handle more than one channel:

```
template<class...Ms>
struct broadcasters : broadcaster<Ms>... {
  using broadcaster<Ms>::reg...;
  using broadcaster<Ms>::send...;

  template<class M>
  broadcaster<M>& station() { return *this; }
};
```

this `broadcasters` is now nearly drop-in improvement on `subject` above.

Due to improvements in `std::function` since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), the `reg` function usually does the right thing unless the signal options are overly similar.  If you do run into problems with `reg` or `send`, you are forced to call `.station<type>().reg(blah)`.

But 99/100 times you can just do a `.reg( lambda )` and `.send( msg )` and overload resolution does the right thing.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a57c78337c696d1).

And here is the entire system augmented with a modular drop-in thread safety system:

```
struct not_thread_safe {
    struct not_lock {~not_lock(){}};
    auto lock() const { return not_lock{}; }
};
struct mutex_thread_safe {
    auto lock() const { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
private:
    mutable std::mutex m;
};
struct rw_thread_safe {
    auto lock() { return std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>(m); }
    auto lock() const { return std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>(m); }
private:
    mutable std::shared_timed_mutex m;
};
template<class D, class>
struct derived_ts {
    auto lock() { return static_cast<D*>(this)->lock(); }
    auto lock() const { return static_cast<D const*>(this)->lock(); }
};
using token = std::shared_ptr<void>;
template<class M, class TS=not_thread_safe>

struct broadcaster:
  TS
{
  using f = std::function< void(M) >;
  mutable std::vector<std::weak_ptr<f>> listeners;
  token reg( f target )
  {
    auto l = this->lock();
    auto sp = std::make_shared<f>(std::move(target));
    listeners.push_back( sp );
    return sp;
  }
  // logically const, but not really:
  void trim() const {
    auto l = const_cast<broadcaster&>(*this).lock();
    auto it = std::remove_if( listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), [](auto&& p){
      return p.expired();
    } );
    listeners.erase( it, listeners.end() );
  }
  // logically const, but not really:
  void send( M m ) const
  {
    trim(); // remove dead listeners
    auto tmp_copy = [this]{
      auto l = this->lock();
      return listeners; // copy the listeners, just in case
    }();

    for (auto w:tmp_copy) {
      auto p = w.lock();
      if (p) (*p)(m);
    }
  }
};
template<class TS, class...Ms>
struct basic_broadcasters :
    TS,
    broadcaster<Ms, derived_ts<basic_broadcasters<TS, Ms...>, Ms> >... 
{
  using TS::lock;
  using broadcaster<Ms, derived_ts<basic_broadcasters<TS, Ms...>, Ms> >::reg...;
  using broadcaster<Ms, derived_ts<basic_broadcasters<TS, Ms...>, Ms> >::send...;

  template<class M>
  broadcaster<M, derived_ts<basic_broadcasters<TS, Ms...>, M>>& station() { return *this; }
  template<class M>
  broadcaster<M, derived_ts<basic_broadcasters<TS, Ms...>, M>> const& station() const { return *this; }
};
template<class...Ms>
using broadcasters = basic_broadcasters<rw_thread_safe, Ms...>;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e4d2fc2ff33bcb8).

`broadcasters<Messages...>` is now a read-write locked broadcasting class that uses 1 common shared lock to synchronize every broadcast queue.

`basic_broadcasters<not_thread_safe, Messages...>` instead creates one with no locking (ie, isn't thread safe).

Comment: Amazing solution. I witnessed it working in the live example and I am still through understanding it -- too clever for my taste / understanding. Sadly I am afraid I wouldn't be able to mantain it at my current understanding of TMP, variadic templates and templates in general (I just don't want to copy and paste it, I really want to understand what it does). Amazing read still, deserving the time to read it many times. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @them to understand it, first examine `broadcaster`.  There is next to no template stuff going on -- so write `broadcaster<int>` yourself (call it `int_broadcaster`).  Work out the `auto` types.  Hook up a listener. The template stuff there is easy.  The `subject` is a `tuple` of `broadcaster`s, with a bit of trickier template code that takes a type, and finds the index of the broadcaster for that type in the tuple.  Then 2 template methods that forward `reg` and `send` to the right broadcaster.  The remaining hard part is `index_of_t`.

Comment: Finally, I find just using raw `broadcaster<string> name_change;` (or whatever `M`) solves most problems.  Make them public data members in the class that needs it: `subject` is far too fancy.

Comment: Actually I gave it a good read at it today and understood a lot of it. I had to skim over the beginning because It's the first few template sentences in the live example where I got lost. All TMP techniques make me dizzy TBH. I am not yet used to 'using', 'typename' and these compile time considerations. The rest I **almost** get: pretty dynamic, on-the-fly code (these lambdas took me a bit to work out until I realized they're being returned and assigned as they're registered). I will continue to make sense of the template beginning. Perhaps throwing some comments on that code?. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick to what will be simpler. If all your observers handles all messages, then you must have one observer type. If the messages are unrelated, each observer mush watch only for the messages it handles.

A solution using Boost::Signal2 would be:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>

class Subject
{
public:
    void emit_message_a(int v) {
        sig_a(v);
    }

    void emit_message_b(const std::string v) {
        sig_b(v);
    }

    template<typename F>
    void register_listener_a(const F &listener)
    {
        sig_a.connect(listener);
    }

    template<typename F>
    void register_listener_b(const F &listener)
    {
        sig_b.connect(listener);
    }

private:
    boost::signals2::signal<void (int)> sig_a;
    boost::signals2::signal<void (std::string)> sig_b;
};

class Observer
{
public:
    Observer():
        name("John")
    {}

    void observe(int v) {
        std::cout << name << " has observed phoenomenon int: " << v << std::endl;
    }

    void observe(std::string v) {
        std::cout << name << " has observed phoenomenon string: " << v << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    Subject s;
    Observer o;

    s.register_listener_a([&](int v){o.observe(v);});
    s.register_listener_b([&](std::string v){o.observe(v);});


    s.register_listener_a([](int val) {
        std::cout << "Received message a : " << val << std::endl;
    });
    s.register_listener_a([](int message_a) {
        printf("I have received message a, too! It is %d.\n", message_a);
    });

    s.register_listener_b([](std::string msg) {
        std::cout << "A B type message was received! Help!\n";
    });

    s.emit_message_a(42);

    s.emit_message_b("a string");

    s.emit_message_a(-1);

    s.emit_message_b("another string");
}
```

Running it, I get:

```
John has observed phoenomenon int: 42
Received message a : 42
I have received message a, too! It is 42.
John has observed phoenomenon string: a string
A B type message was received! Help!
John has observed phoenomenon int: -1
Received message a : -1
I have received message a, too! It is -1.
John has observed phoenomenon string: another string
A B type message was received! Help!
```

If you are going to use it, be sure to read [the manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ivelia. The boost solution seems easy to code and to understand : I am giving a read to the manual as we type. Still I don't think I am gonna use it as of now, but keep it bookmarked. I will, however, take your advice of keeping it simple (it's easy to get wound up on "what if" cases). Thanks a lot!.